# Centering labels at the bars using ggplot2 and moving labels to the top of the errorbar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, errorbar

With the code below,

```
library(ggplot2)
load(url("http://murraylax.org/datasets/cps2016.RData"))

ggplot(df, aes(industry, usualhrs, fill=as.factor(sex))) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, position = "dodge", width=0.7) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge", width=0.7) + 
  stat_summary(aes(label = round(..y..,0)), fun = mean, geom = "text", size = 3, vjust = -1) +  
  xlab("Industry") + ylab("Usual Hourly Earnings") +  
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 12)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  labs(fill = "Gender")  +
  theme_bw()
```

I am producing this barplot (with error bars):

[image: Output]

The labels are centered according to the x-axis, but I would like to have the labels centered in each bar. In the first two bars, for example, I would like to have 27 at the center of the "Female" bar and 46 at the center of "Male" bar. I would also like to move the labels to the top of the error bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position = position_dodge(width = 1))` to your `stat_summary(aes(label...))` call, outside of `aes` to move the labels above their respective bars.

To move the labels above the error bars I used `geom_text` with a y position slightly above the error bars, which required calculating the error bar position ahead of time using `dplyr::summarize`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(industry, sex) %>% 
  summarise(usualhrs_mean = mean(usualhrs, na.rm = TRUE),
            count = n(),
            usualhrs_se = sd(usualhrs, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = industry, y = usualhrs_mean, fill = as.factor(sex))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = usualhrs_mean - usualhrs_se,
                    ymax = usualhrs_mean + usualhrs_se), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(..y.., 0), y = (usualhrs_mean + usualhrs_se + 0.1)), vjust = -1.5, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x)
      str_wrap(x, width = 12)
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 55)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(fill = "Gender",
       y = "Usual Hourly Earnings")  +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I got the following error with your code, @Greg: Error: n() should only be called in a data context

Comment: @Thiago - I suspect this is a package conflict with something else you have loaded.  Try specifying `dplyr::summarize`, `dplyr::n` etc.

Comment: how to keep the distance between bars the same as in the original plot using your code? I mean: the two bars per category (in the x-axis) together and the bars between categories more distant?

Comment: @Thiago change `width` in `position = position_dodge()` to 0.7.